# How to check whether one class is inhereted of another class?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm using Ext4...

How to check whether one class is inherited of another class?

for example:

```
Ext.define("A", {});
Ext.define("B", { extend: "A" });
Ext.define("C", { extend: "B" });

var a = Ext.create("A");
var c = Ext.create("C");
```

I need something like this:
    c instanceof a

???

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, but did you try with `c instanceof a`? That would work in Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Based on @troelskn 's comment)

http://jsfiddle.net/miriam/ugQHB/

```
c instanceof A
```

returns true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use isXtype method. See docs here: [Ext.AbstractComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-isXType)

Comment: it is not exactly what I meant, but thanks, I didn't know this method! :)